# How can I call a method along with its parameters?

Tags: java

```
public class Testing{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double salary;
private String subject;
private String highestDegree;
private int years;


public Testing 
(String first, String last, String sub, String degree, double sal, int year)
//constructor being called in the main method.
    {
        lastName = last;
        firstName = first;
        subject = sub;
        highestDegree = degree;
        salary = sal;
        years = year;
    }
public class Hello{

 public static void main(String []args){
    //Part missing
 }
}
```

I did the setters and getters, all I'm missing is how to call that constructor in the main method. I was thinking on creating a new object like Testing in = new Testing() but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something else. And if there's more things that I might be missing please let me know. I'm learning java.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about it? Have you tried anything? Received any compiler errors?

Comment: Are you just asking how to call the constructor? Because that's easy - `Testing in = new Testing( first, last, sub, degree, sal, year )`, where those arguments are either variables you've defined before the call, or literal values. Or are you also asking how to get those arguments from the command line?

Comment: Please read the Java Tutorial!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have defined a custom Constructor
`public Testing (String first, String last, String sub, String degree, double sal, int year)`

you cannot use the default constructor.

```
Testing in = new Testing() // Not allowed now
```

You would have to use your constructor to define, instantiate, and initialize objects of class `Testing`.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String first = "userName";
    ...
    ...

    Testing in = new Testing(first, last, sub, degree, sal, year)
}
```

Comment: ooh, T_T It makes sense now. Thanks so much!